# MS Access, I am tasked with rewriting an MS Access application

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to locate a query, and cannot find it.

Where can I find qMyQuery?

```
Dim stDocName As String

stDocName = "qMyQuery"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
```

Answer (score 0):

By pressing F11 in Access 2010 you can open the navigation pane (if not already open). From here, select “Queries” or “All Objects” using the small down arrow at the top of the navigation pane to view the queries in the mdb.

Answer (score 0):

type this `docmd.SelectObject acQuery ,"qMyQuery",true` an press `Enter`
in "Immediate" window and Access will select your Query in database window.
To open "Immediate" window you can press `Ctrl+G`